# How to design a measuring cup with constant errors for any depth of liquid?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A [recent Kickstarter project](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1075898346/euclid-a-more-accurate-measuring-cup) aims to design a measuring cup which has a constant volume-error, independent of the height of the liquid in the cup. To do this they claim to solve the equation

$$
     f(h) = k*\int_0^h {f(t) dt}
$$

However if you differentiate both sides of that equation and solve the resulting differential equation you get a solution of $C \ast \mathrm{exp}(kh)$ and that solution does not satisfy the original differential equation.

How is the solution obtained?